# Printing Uppercase/Lowercase letters

Tags: c

I'm doing a program that is asking the user to enter a stream of characters and printing out the number of uppercase and lowercase letters. I'm trying to do it with a function, but having some trouble printing it..for every character input im entering im getting `0, 0`
Would appreciate your help to understand what am I doing wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int case_letters(int ch);

int main(void)

{
    int x;
    printf("please enter a some characters, and ctrl + d to see result\n");

    case_letters(x);

    return 0;
}

int case_letters(int ch)

{
    int numOfUpper = 0;
    int numOfLower = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if ((ch = isdigit(ch)) || ch == '\n')
        {
            printf("please enter a valid character\n");
            continue;
        }


        else if ((ch = isupper(ch)))
        {
            numOfUpper++;
        }

        else if ((ch = islower(ch)))
        {
            numOfLower++;
        }

    }

    return  printf("%d, %d", numOfUpper, numOfLower);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your `if` statements assign different value to `ch` and do not check `ch`'s value.

For example, if you enter a correct `char`, this

```
if ((ch = isdigit(ch)) || ch == '\n')
```

will assign `0` to `ch`, because `isdigit(ch)` will return `0`. I guess you need

```
if ( isdigit(ch) || ch == '\n')
```

Same for `islower` and `isupper`.

Comment: thanks allot! got it now :) is how i called the function is ok though? in the main @meh

Comment: Basically, it's fine. But, I'd remove the parameter and I'd declare `ch` inside the function, not in the `main`. And print the message again in the function, not in the `main`. In other words, I'd write my `main` like this: `int main(void) { case_letters(); return 0; }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ((ch = isdigit(ch)) || ch == '\n')
            ^-- assignment, not equality test.
```

You're trashing the value of `ch` with the return value of isdigit(), and isupper(), and islower(), so that the original user-entered value is destroyed as soon as you do the isdigit test.

Try

```
    if (isdigit(ch) || ch == '\n')
    else if (isupper(ch))
    else if (islower(ch))
```

instead. No need to preserve the iswhatever values.